# Is there anyway to change the text/icon that is shown when dragging an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, plupload, jquery-draggable

I am using plupload (http://www.plupload.com/). It has the ability to drag and drop photos to be uploaded.

In IE, the text says "Move"

[image: IE]

In Chrome, the text says "Copy"

[image: Chrome]

Is there anyway to specify to IE that I want it to show the Copy icon?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using Javascript. This part is from the operating system. When you drag a file to an application, Chrome tells the OS it will make a copy and IE says it will move the file.